# Conditional URL with ternary operator in a href tag in JavaScript

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, sharepoint-rest-api

Can anyone help me in writing ternary operator in JavaScript in below line if href is empty set `data.d.results[i].EncodedAbsUrl` else `data.d.results[i].ServerRedirectedEmbedUrl`

```
listItemInfo += "<div class=panel-heading><h4><a target='_blank' href='"+data.d.results[i].ServerRedirectedEmbedUrl+"'>"+data.d.results[i].FileLeafRef+"</a></h4><p>"+String.format("{0:d}",new Date(data.d.results[i].Created))+",&nbsp;"+data.d.results[i].Author.FirstName+"&nbsp;"+data.d.results[i].Author.LastName+"</p></div>";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I understand what you're asking. Are you looking for something like this?

```
var href = data.d.results[i].ServerRedirectedEmbedUrl ? data.d.results[i].ServerRedirectedEmbedUrl : data.d.results[i].EncodedAbsUrl;

listItemInfo += "<div class=panel-heading><h4><a target='_blank' href='"+href+"'>"+data.d.results[i].FileLeafRef+"</a></h4><p>"+String.format("{0:d}",new Date(data.d.results[i].Created))+",&nbsp;"+data.d.results[i].Author.FirstName+"&nbsp;"+data.d.results[i].Author.LastName+"</p></div>";
```